# there isn´t method success in sequelize.sync

Tags: node.js

I´ve the following code, imports the model
[image]

I get the error in line 11. Doesn´t exist method success

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sequelize uses the [`bluebird`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) package for its Promise implementation, and [as you can see here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md), its API doesn't support `.success()` (which also isn't a valid Promises/A+ method).

Instead, use [`.then()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#thenfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise):

```
sequelize.sync().then(function() {
  ...called if successful...
}, function(err) {
  ...called if an error occurred...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

in addition to @robertklep answer, success() is deprecated so you need then() function instead.

The result would be:

```
sequelize.sync().then(function() {
    Quiz.count().then(function (count){
        if(count === 0) {
            Quiz.create({ 
                pregunta: 'Capital de Italia',
                respuesta: 'Roma'
            })
            .then(function(){console.log('log')});
        }
    });
});
```

The same in quiz_controller.js